# iOS adding a top bar as a subview

Tags: ios, button, view, imageview, subview

I am currently working on an app for iPhone where I have an Imageview showing off some images and via swipe I can change the images.

But I'm currently trying to add a subview that will be a top bar, and when the image is touched, it will make this top bar slide down from the top.

The current code I've tried to do this with is:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 60.0f);
UIView *topBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:topBar];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:topBar];
```

But the topbar won't show up, and I have logs showing that the touches are recognized.

How do I do this, and how do I properly populate the subview with buttons?

Best Regards.

FreeSirenety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topBar has nothing in it, so how can you know it has been added?

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 60.0f);
UIView *topBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
topBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:topBar];
```

Also you don't need to use the bringSubViewToFront as the view that's gets added as a subview is always the topMost in the view hierarchy!